# Where in windows 10 registry is user's theme color

Tags: windows, colors, hex, registry

I want to ask you guys, where in windows 10 registry is user's theme color? I mean that color, what is displayed on Taskbar, in Action Center, Start, Live Tiles and windows' borders. Thanks for any reply.

Comment: There is no documented registry location for these colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 10 you can [get the users accent color](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170405-00/?p=95905) from the UISettings interface. In Windows 8 you are mostly stuck with [undocumented functions](https://www.quppa.net/blog/2013/01/02/retrieving-windows-8-theme-colours/).